# Android GreenDao - How to compare to two date strings?

Tags: android, date, greendao

I have few string properties with custom type `java.util.Date` added in `MainGenerator` class. 
In `querybuilder` how can I compare these strings with ge or le or gt or lt. 
I save the db values in string type and I compare them like this

`qb.queryBuilder().where(TestDao.Properties.Date_entered.ge(start)).list();`

It doesn't work.

Comment: What is the sample value of start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using greenDao then in your MainGenerator you must be having the date as

```
testdao.addDateProperty("date_entered").notNull();
```

So in `qb.queryBuilder().where(TestDao.Properties.Date_entered.ge(start)).list();`

**start** should be **java.util.Date**.

Answer (score 1):

Dates are persisted as timestamps of type long. Thus, for your query parameters, you should also use long values.

Comment: can you put down an example?

Comment: so in this query qb.queryBuilder().where(TestDao.Properties.Date_entered.ge(start)).list()    start should be long value?

Comment: You can use either Date or Long (ie. date.getTime()). They both work. This is [explained in the documentation](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/queries/#Custom_Types_as_Parameters). Take a look at the source code of the class `WhereCondition` if you are curious.

Answer (score 1):

First Parse your date in String as you are saving date in database in string format. Then query data. Here is sample code.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
//Modify Calendar here according to your requirement.

dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
//Check if you have different date format then replace in above line.

String dateString = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

//Then query your data
qb.queryBuilder().where(TestDao.Properties.Date_entered.ge(dateString )).list();
```

Comment: @user1810931 waqas ali  if your date entered is a dateProperty and you do this solution, you will get this exception.  Illegal date value: expected java.util.Date or Long for value ..... So i don't think this is the correct answer

Comment: I think i have already mentioned above that this solution is valid if you are saving date in String format. You need to re read the first line of answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert String date into milliseconds and can compare the values for your result:

```
   public boolean checkDates(String date1, String date2) {
            long milliDate1 = getMilliFromDate(date1);
            long milliDate2 = getMilliFromDate(date2);

            //Check date according to your requirement and condition
            return milliDate1 < milliDate2;
        }

        public long getMilliFromDate(String dateFormat) {
            Date date = new Date();
        // "dd/MM/yyyy" this is date format i use you can use your own
        //format which you are storing in local database like time stamp "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            try {
                date = formatter.parse(dateFormat);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return date.getTime();
        }
```